# Error with 2D array - Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops

The first 2 loops set the textfields just fine. But the next 2 give me the error Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. Something is NULL, but what? Can't figure out :(

```
import flash.text.TextField;

var suallar:Array = new Array();
var cavablar_temp:Array = new Array();

var i:int;
var j:int;

suallar.push(["sual1", "duz1", "sehv11", "sevh12", "sevh13","sevh14"]);
suallar.push(["sual2", "duz2", "sehv21", "sevh22","sevh23","sevh24" ]);
suallar.push(["sual3", "duz3", "sehv31", "sevh32","sevh33","sevh34"]);
suallar.push(["sual4", "duz4", "sehv41", "sevh42","sevh43","sevh44"]);
suallar.push(["sual5", "duz5", "sehv51", "sevh52","sevh53","sevh54"]);

var sualYeri:Array = new Array();
for (i=0; i<suallar.length; i++)
{
    sualYeri[i] = new TextField();
}




for (i=0; i<suallar.length; i++)
{
    sualYeri[i].text = suallar[i][0];

    sualYeri[i].x = 0;
    sualYeri[i].y = 50 * i;
    addChild(sualYeri[i]);
}

trace(sualYeri.join("\n"));
trace(suallar.join("\n"));
```

last 2 loops, that don't work start here

```
var cavabYeri:Array = new Array();

for (i=0; i<suallar.length; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<suallar.length; j++)
    {
        cavabYeri[i][j] = new TextField();

    }
}
trace(cavabYeri.join("\n"));



for (i=0; i<suallar.length; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<suallar[i].length; j++)
    {
        cavabYeri[i][j].text = suallar[i][j];

        cavabYeri[i][j].x = 0 + 100 * j;
        cavabYeri[i][j].y = 0 + 100 * i;
        addChild(cavabYeri[i][j]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what language are the names of your variables in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you initialized the `cavabYeri` array but not its subarrays.

```
for (i=0; i<suallar.length; i++)
{
    cavabYeri[i] = []; // or new Array();
    for (j=0; j<suallar.length; j++)
    {
        cavabYeri[i][j] = new TextField();
    }
}
```

Comment: almost sure, that you are right... going to check now :) thankS!

Answer (score 2):

You're having the exact same problem as what exists in [this question that I've answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269332/as3-multidimensional-array/9269347#9269347).

You can't immediately assign values to `array[i][j]` without first creating an array at `array[i]`.